# Add sorting options for search results

Tags: feature-request, bug, search, sorting, android-app

On opening a site feed, sorting options are available for questions.

[image]

These however, are not available after entering a search query.

[image]

It should be possible to sort search results just like in the site feed.

Version: 0.1.36

Comment: is this a feature-request or a bug? can you prove it's a bug and not status-by-design?

Comment: @mehow: He's assuming it's a bug because it does exist elsewhere, while it might not be a bug and in which case it's a feature request :D All bases covered.